# Saving and Retrieving Uploaded File in Access 2010 Database

Tags: c#, database, file-upload

I want to save an uploaded file (a jpg image, for instance) in my database, which was built in Microsoft Access 2010, and I have no idea how. I use C# in code behind of web page.
I read some articles but they refer to sql databases, which consist of binary fields (what I didn't see it possible in Access). Most of these articles converted the file to an array of bytes.

There is another way to do that?

Note: my database is .mdb file.

Comment: Probably, you could encode image as `base64` string and store it in a `string` field.

Answer (score 1):

In Access Databases you can use "OLE Object" fields to store binary information.

You can insert an image into an OLE Object field like this:

```
string imagePath = @"C:\Users\Me\Pictures\rubic.png";
byte[] imageBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(imagePath);

using (var conn = new OleDbConnection(
    @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Data\access.mdb"))
{
    using (var cmd = new OleDbCommand(
        "INSERT INTO tblImages ([image], [name]) VALUES (@1, @2)", conn))
    {
        conn.Open();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@1", imageBytes);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@2", "Rubic's cube");
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

And you can retrieve the image with:

```
string imageSavePath = @"C:\Users\Me\Desktop\test.png";
byte[] imageBytes;

using (var conn = new OleDbConnection(
    @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Data\access.mdb"))
{
    using (var cmd = new OleDbCommand(
        "SELECT [image] FROM tblImages WHERE id = 1", conn))
    {
        conn.Open();
        imageBytes = (byte[])cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    }
}
File.WriteAllBytes(imageSavePath, imageBytes);
```

This works for any kind of binary data.

The Jet OleDb provider works only in 32 bits. So compile your code with the x86 option.

Comment: Is it possible to save the image in a folder in the server, and send to the database the image path as a string type, and just convert it to image in the retrieving? Note: The folder will be found in the web service.

Comment: Yes, use an Access `Image` control. You can set its `Picture` property to a file path. `If Nz(FilePath) = "" Then Me!image.Visible = False Else Me!image.Picture = FilePath Me!image.Visible = True End If`